# While creating a pipeline in Azure DevOps I am not able to select the subscription option?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using a free trial in Azure and I am creating a Docker container but the issue is I was not able to select the Free Trial option.  I thought this might be a glitch so I logged out several times and recreated the whole pipeline but still the issue is there. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the screenshot.
[image]

So, I put that manually, and after authorization, it is visible in the dropdown as shown in the attached image. But still when I click on it to select it is not selected and the input field is blank.

Comment: Can you try to manually input the name of the service connection in the subscription option? Will it still show blank?

Comment: Yeah I tried but then there was an error stating that this service connection already exists.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are using the docker task version 0.

You can change to use the newer version(version 1 or 2) of the Docker task.

For example:

[image]

When you use Docker task version 1, you can keep using the current service connection.

If you change to use the Docker task version 2, you need to change to use the Docker Register Service connection.

[image]

You can click the **+ New** option to create a new Docker Registry service connection

Comment: I tried this also but whatever version I select it remains 0 and no other option is selected.

Comment: @AbdulSamad Can you change to use other browsers to do the same steps and check if it can work(e.g, edge chrome)?

Comment: I tried it on Edge also earlier I was using Chrome but still same issue is there. Do you think this might be the problem with Free Trial only?

Comment: NO. The issue should not be related to Free Trial.  Because when you change the task version, it even keeps showing version 0. If possible , you can create the an empty pipeline and manually add the docker task to the Pipeline job.

Comment: @AbdulSamad Is there any update about this ticket?

Comment: Actually this problem was not resolved so I tried the paid version and there it worked fine but in free trial this issue is still there.